# can not be aligned to the flexbox

Tags: html, flexbox

I want to do input's in the center.
Her it is the code:

```css
    .input-container{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center
    
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
    <script src="/webcam.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS.css">
    </head>
    
    <body class="body">
    
     <div class="input-container">
           <input class="login" placeholder="login">
           <input class="password" placeholder="password">
     </div>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

But you can not do it in the center. But in theory it should. What could be the problem. Thank you for your time!

Comment: They are in the centre.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Explain what you mean by center? 2 inputs in the same row? Right now they are centered but in 2 rows

Comment: at the centered of the page!
according to the documentation on the site about the flexbox. Must be centered on my items!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 100% height to body, html, and your container.

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.input-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

should solve your issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/m6wet5c7/7/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
flex-flow: row wrap;
```

To make them align in center sidebyside.